# How to disable date detection in elastic search using java api?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am creating index using dynamic mapping from input json, But in my json date parameter am passing as a String, But ES was considering as a date, And i found the issue But i dont know how to apply through JAVA Api in ES, below mapping i needs to do it in ES java api..? Any help will be appreciate Thanks in advance..

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "date_detection": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the [Put Mapping API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-put-mapping.html) for the Java Client.  It will let you create and set mappings for your indices.

It includes Synchronous and Asynchronous execution, Mapping source and what to expect after using it.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: I don't want to define mapping , am using dynamic mapping  just I need to set the date detection false